# Redirect the output outside the output file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch which call another batch file. Lets call them b1 and b2. Here is the code inside my 2 batch files.

b1 :

```
@echo off

call b2.cmd 1>output.txt
```

and b2 :

```
@echo off

echo "I want this in output.txt"
echo "I want this in the cmd window" 1>&1
```

After executing my script I got :

output.txt :

```
"I want this in output.txt"
```

and in the command line :

```
The handle couldn't be duplicated during the redirection of the handle 1.
```

(which is : "Le handle n’a pas pu être dupliqué lors de la redirection du handle 1." in french, (and sry for the bad traduction))

And I want to have :

output.txt :

```
"I want this in output.txt"
```

and in the command line :

```
"I want this in the cmd window"
```

**Do someone have any idea to make this output ?**

If you need any details, ask me and I will try to help you.

PS : I can have more than 1 intermediate file (like b1 call b2, b2 call b3, etc) and I still want to print something from the last file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "I want this in the cmd window" 1>con
```

worked for me.